# Is my code malicious?

Tags: javascript, ajax

In a few pages of my website I show some information to my visitors. This information needs to be current (max 30 minutes old) otherwise it's not only useless but misleading too.

To get this kind of information I need about 2-3 seconds. My site tries it's best to refresh every page once per 30 minutes but this is not always possible.

When a user visits a page with expired information, in the past I did the following:

1. Show a loading bar
2. Do an Ajax call to the server and tell him refresh the information on the database
3. When the server replies done, use document.write to replace the whole page

**Some of my users got security warnings from this when posting the link on Facebook!** I immediately modified my code and now I do the following (It just got live):

1. Show a loading bar
2. Do an Ajax call to the server and tell him refresh the information on the database
3. When the server replies done, refresh the page via javascript - location.reload();

**Question: #1**: Why the document.write is considered malicious? Is my new solution considered malicious too?

**Question: #2**: Will Google penalize my new solution?

Also if you have any suggestion on how can I improve this please let me know!

Comment: If you're going to replace the whole page, why use ajax at all? Why not just post an ordinary form and let the browser do its thing?

Comment: @Pointy: I am sorry, I don't understand what you mean... What do you mean 'post an ordinary form'?

Comment: When you POST a `<form>` from a web page in the ordinary, old-fashioned way, the returned HTML from the server replaces the entire page. (I guess it's the same when you have a GET form, which might be more proper in your case.)

Comment: @Pointy: I see... so you mean when the user visits the page start the post immediately without having him submit anything?

Comment: document.write isn't malicious, it's just not very secure.  I'd do things in a different way.  Possibly you could hold your data in memory instead of having to hit the server for the same info every thirty minutes? As far as Question #2 is concerned...Google doesn't penalize anyone for their code.  AngularJS is the only thing Google cares about!

Comment: I think this may help you : `https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax`

Comment: @Pointy: Maybe my post is confusing, but they user doesn't submit anything. When he/she visits the page he/she waits for the data to be prepared.

Comment: The user doesn't have to click submit for you to submit a form, you could do something like `document.getElementById('myFormId').submit();` to submit it. A better solution though might be to have a cron job running every 30 minutes or so to avoid the issue all together.

Comment: Can you give some more context on what you are trying to do?   Is this like a stock ticker chart or something?

Comment: @winhowes: I am running a cron job. But due to bandwidth limitations not everything can be updated on time. There is nothing I can do about this.

Comment: @dave: It's for price/stock purposes, as you said.

Comment: You can post a form whenever you want; the point is that it's simpler to just post a form than to rig up an ajax request and then obliterate the document with your own code. You could also just update `window.location`!

Comment: In today's day and age, preferably you wouldn't have to reload your whole page to refresh its content. You would either (a) Do an AJAX query for just the main part of the page and just replace that part, or (b) Do an AJAX query for the needed _data_ (usually in the form of JSON) and build the main part of your page from scratch or using a JS templating engine. But in the short run, using a `window.location` redirect should be enough to eliminate the use of `document.write`.

Comment: @Pointy: Thanks! So my 2nd solution with `location.reload();` is better?

Comment: Does anyone have any idea why Facebook considers document.write unsafe?

Comment: @ChessPlayer Because it _is_ unsafe (and it's also extremely outdated). On a separate note, is there a reason why you undid my edit? Code blocks are for posting code, not numbered lists.

Comment: @JLRishe: I am sorry, please edit back my post.

Comment: @ChessPlayer well it certainly seems a lot simpler :)